# no se puede iniciar el servidor web de iis express visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis

Asi de repente queria depurar mi proyecto y comenzo a lanzar el error: 
no se puede iniciar el servidor web de iis express

WebConfig

```html
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=blabla/blabla;Initial Catalog=blabla;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="webopt" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"
          assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation"
        preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución es buscar y eliminar la carpeta ".vs" (puede ser una carpeta oculta) debajo de la carpeta de la solución, volver a abrir el proyecto y se ejecutará normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

tuve  este error en visual studio  2017 y  2019,

este error trata sobre los puertos asp.net  que no estan funcionado bien

Ejemplo estos puerto que miran aquí 
    http://localhost:55399

debe realizar posicionarme sobre el proyecto darle clic derecho, ir hasta del modal 
y darle clic a propiedades. en este momento se abrirá configuraciones. y le damos clic en depurar bajos un poco. Encontraremos  dirección Url de la aplicación entoces debilitamos  la opción habilitar SSL y en  dirección Url  realizamos el cambio de puertos.

Como hacemos el cambio  de puertos creamos nuevo proyecto  asp.net. Realizamos el mismo proceso anterior y copiamos toda la dirección url que nos aparezca en el  proyecto nuevo y lo copiamos en el otro proyecto  del problema y  asi  solucionado el error.

[image: Este las propiedades de proyecto]